# error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive] with a system command line

Tags: c++, string-literals

I'm trying run a `netsh` command with the `system()` function in C++.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream> // cin / cout
#include<stdlib.h> // system()
using namespace std;

int main(){

    system('netsh interface show interface | findstr /C:"Wi-Fi" /C:"Name"');

}
```

I think that I need to add something before the `'netsh` to solve this error but I don't know what character, I already try: `system(L'netsh interface show interface | findstr /C:"Wi-Fi" /C:"Name"');` but no success,

Comment: Voting to close as typo. Strings literals in C++ are enclosed in `"`, not `'`, and `"` must be escaped with `\"` inside string literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in a [**multi-character literal**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) instead of a [**string literal**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).  Using single-quotes `'...'` creates a single `char`, which is a numeric type that can be promoted to `int`, that is why you are getting the error about an `int` being passed in where a `const char*` is expected.  `system()` expects a null-terminated C-style string instead, ie an array of `char` values ending with the `'\0'` character.  In string literal form, you use double-quotes `"..."` instead to create such an array.

You need to replace the `'` characters with `"`. And then you also need to *escape* the inner `"` characters using `\`, eg:

```
system("netsh interface show interface | findstr /C:\"Wi-Fi\" /C:\"Name\"");
```

Alternatively, in C++11 and later, you can use a **raw string literal** instead to avoid escaping the inner `"` characters:

```
system(R"(netsh interface show interface | findstr /C:"Wi-Fi" /C:"Name")");
```